# InvalidMemoryOperationError@ on call of class destructor

Tags: d

The plan is to log message using template when a class destructor is called, but it seems to not be possible. Any suggestions or explanations will be appreciated.

```
import std.stdio;
import std.datetime;

class Test
{
    this()
    {
        struct Start
        {
            string filename;
        }
        Message!(Start)(Start("one.txt\n"));
    }

    ~this()
    {
        struct Stop
        {
            string filename;
        }

        Message!(Stop)(Stop("stop one.txt\n"));  // > core.exception.InvalidMemoryOperationError@(0)
        // auto t = Clock.currTime().toISOString(); // > core.exception.InvalidMemoryOperationError@(0
    }
}

unittest
{
    auto t = new Test();
}

struct Message(T)
{
    this(T message)
    {
        _time = Clock.currTime().toISOString();
        writefln("%s: %s", _time, message.filename);
    }
    string _time;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not allowed to allocate GC memory while the GC is running. Since class destructors are typically run by the GC, the result is you shouldn't use it in there.

It is also worth noting that accessing other GC members by reference is disallowed in class destructors, since an object's members may be freed at the same time as the object itself, and thus be unavailable in that context.

So the trick is to get rid of that toISOString call and the implicit call to struct.toString.

This will work better:

```
struct Message(T)
{
    this(T message)
    {
        auto time = Clock.currTime();
        writefln("%d:%02d:%02d %s(%s)",
          time.hour, time.minute, time.second,
          T.stringof, message.filename);
    }
}
```

By building the string ourselves in writefln out of the components instead of relying on a function that returns a new string, we stop the allocations, preventing the exception.

Comment: Excellent answer. BTW - I bought your Cook Book last year - a very good read and exposes some interesting concepts and what can be done with D.